# ggplot: facets with their own order of factors on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, facet-grid

There have been many similar questions but did not find exactly what I was looking for. I have the following dataset:

```
dat<-data.frame(Pal=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=5),
            Rol=c("aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa"),
            Cel=rep(c("home","tree","hat","ball","pen","rope"),times=c(5,3,2,5,2,3)),
            Value=c(7701.1,59897.3,59897.3,59897.3,744438.1,1226.4,1454.6,1454.6,1454.6,1454.6,56600,92400,5010000,7010000,15740000,28.5,34.2,39.9,48.5,57),
            Col=c("black","red","black","black","red","red","red","black","black","black","red","red","red","red","red","red","black","black","black","black"),
            Effect=c("length","length","length","length","height","weight","length","length","age of youngest individual found miles from the closest coastline","age of youngest individual found miles from the closest coastline","pressure","speed","rate","rate","length","length","rate","rate","O2","fecundity")
            )
```

I'm trying to build a slightly complex graph as the one you can see below:

```
highlights<-data.frame(Pal=c("A","B","C","D"))
highlights$Pal<-factor(highlights$Pal,levels=c("A","B","C","D"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data=highlights,aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=1, ymax=1000000000), fill=c("yellow","blue","red","green"), alpha=0.05) +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=Effect, y=Value, shape=Rol, col=Col)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=unique(dat$Col), values=as.character(unique(dat$Col))) +
  labs(x="",y="Activity") + facet_grid(.~Pal, scales = "free_x")+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1,1000000000),breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,100000000,1000000000)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 40)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

I would like to have the data points to be in an increasing order within each facet. Since the data are already sorted in that way, I have tried to use the "facet_grid_sc" function from the "facetscales" library to create individual facet x-axis scale based on the unique "Effect" column I have in the data as following:

```
my_scales <- list(
  "A" = scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(unique(dat[which(dat$Pal=="A"),"Effect"]))),
  "B" = scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(unique(dat[which(dat$Pal=="B"),"Effect"]))),
  "C" = scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(unique(dat[which(dat$Pal=="C"),"Effect"]))),
  "D" = scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(unique(dat[which(dat$Pal=="D"),"Effect"])))
)


ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data=highlights,aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=1, ymax=1000000000), fill=c("yellow","blue","red","green"), alpha=0.05) +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=Effect, y=Value, shape=Rol, col=Col)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=unique(dat$Col), values=as.character(unique(dat$Col))) +
  labs(x="",y="Activity") + facet_grid_sc(cols = vars(Pal), scales=list(x = my_scales)) +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1,1000000000),breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,100000000,1000000000)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 40)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

While this way it solves the problem as I have data points in an increasing order, it completely screws up the plot. Does any of you have a solution for this? Highly appreciated

Thanks

EDIT: Following @Quentin answer, I do provide a slightly larger randomly generated dataset for which the solution seems not to work:

```
dat<-data.frame(Pal=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),times=c(20,40,60,30)),
                Rol=c(rep("aa",15),rep("bb",5),rep("aa",40),rep("cc",60),rep("aa",30)),
                Cel=rep(c("home","tree","hat","ball","arm","leg","beer","stick","pen","rope"),times=c(15,13,12,12,13,12,15,18,17,23)),
                Value=c(runif(n=20,min = 7000, max = 100000),runif(n=40,min = 100, max = 100000),runif(n=60,min = 1000, max = 1000000),runif(n=30,min = 100000, max = 10000000)),
                Col=rep(c("red","black"),each=5,times=15),
                Effect=c(rep(c("length","height"),times=c(15,5)),rep(c("weight","length","age of youngest individual found miles from the closest coastline"),times=c(10,7,23)),rep(c("pressure","speed","rate","length"),times=c(10,3,7,40)),rep(c("length","rate","O2","fecundity"),times=c(3,4,7,16)))
)
```

Any fixing to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit after comment**

You should slightly modify the `reorder_within` function, by setting `max` instead of `mean` like this:

```r
dat<-data.frame(Pal=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),times=c(20,40,60,30)),
                Rol=c(rep("aa",15),rep("bb",5),rep("aa",40),rep("cc",60),rep("aa",30)),
                Cel=rep(c("home","tree","hat","ball","arm","leg","beer","stick","pen","rope"),times=c(15,13,12,12,13,12,15,18,17,23)),
                Value=c(runif(n=20,min = 7000, max = 100000),runif(n=40,min = 100, max = 100000),runif(n=60,min = 1000, max = 1000000),runif(n=30,min = 100000, max = 10000000)),
                Col=rep(c("red","black"),each=5,times=15),
                Effect=c(rep(c("length","height"),times=c(15,5)),rep(c("weight","length","age of youngest individual found miles from the closest coastline"),times=c(10,7,23)),rep(c("pressure","speed","rate","length"),times=c(10,3,7,40)),rep(c("length","rate","O2","fecundity"),times=c(3,4,7,16)))
)

library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = max, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

highlights<-data.frame(Pal=c("A","B","C","D"))
highlights$Pal<-factor(highlights$Pal,levels=c("A","B","C","D"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data=highlights,aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=1, ymax=1000000000), fill=c("yellow","blue","red","green"), alpha=0.05) +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=reorder_within(Effect, Value, Pal), y=Value, shape=Rol, col=Col)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=unique(dat$Col), values=as.character(unique(dat$Col))) +
  labs(x="",y="Activity") + facet_grid(.~Pal, scales = "free_x")+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1,1000000000),breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,100000000,1000000000)) +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Old answer**

You can use the functions `reorder_within` and `scale_x_reordered` from this [GitHub](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R) like this:

```r
dat<-data.frame(Pal=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=5),
                Rol=c("aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa"),
                Cel=rep(c("home","tree","hat","ball","pen","rope"),times=c(5,3,2,5,2,3)),
                Value=c(7701.1,59897.3,59897.3,59897.3,744438.1,1226.4,1454.6,1454.6,1454.6,1454.6,56600,92400,5010000,7010000,15740000,28.5,34.2,39.9,48.5,57),
                Col=c("black","red","black","black","red","red","red","black","black","black","red","red","red","red","red","red","black","black","black","black"),
                Effect=c("length","length","length","length","height","weight","length","length","age of youngest individual found miles from the closest coastline","age of youngest individual found miles from the closest coastline","pressure","speed","rate","rate","length","length","rate","rate","O2","fecundity")
)

library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

highlights<-data.frame(Pal=c("A","B","C","D"))
highlights$Pal<-factor(highlights$Pal,levels=c("A","B","C","D"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data=highlights,aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=1, ymax=1000000000), fill=c("yellow","blue","red","green"), alpha=0.05) +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=reorder_within(Effect, Value, Pal), y=Value, shape=Rol, col=Col)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=unique(dat$Col), values=as.character(unique(dat$Col))) +
  labs(x="",y="Activity") + facet_grid(.~Pal, scales = "free_x")+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1,1000000000),breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,100000000,1000000000)) +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Quinten! It seems to work but when you try with a larger dataset it seems there are some issues. I did edit the question adding a larger dataset for which your solution seems not to work. Do you have any additional insight on how to fix this? Would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hi @Bithorax, I slightly modified the function to `max` instead of `mean`, now it should work!

Comment: Hi @Quinten, thanks! However, I'm actually wondering whether I did not explain clearly what I was trying to achieve and apologise for that. So basically, within each facet, I want the data points to be ordered so that each "Effect" is ordered depending on its smallest value. To give you an example, in the last plot you produced, if you take facet "C", the right order of the effects should be length, speed, rate and pressure. To make it clearer, the order should be only based on the lowest data point for each effect. Did you get what I mean? Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @Bithorax, than you should use in the function min instead of max.

Comment: @Quintin yes! I actually modified it before you just commented :) Thanks a lot!